# MySQL stored procedure UPDATE changing first row only

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following `watching` table

[image]

If I run this simple test query:

```
UPDATE 
    `watching`
SET 
    `lastPriceSeen` = 1.33 
WHERE 
    `email` = 'blablanfff@gmail.com' AND 
    `productId` = 254857265 
LIMIT 1
```

row ID 10 correctly updates to 1.33 in the `lastPriceSeen` column

If I convert this to a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateLastSeenPrice`(
    email VARCHAR(100),
    productId INT(11),
    price FLOAT
)
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Updates watcher last seen price'
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        `watching`
    SET 
        `lastPriceSeen` = price 
    WHERE 
        `email` = email AND 
        `productId` = productId 
    LIMIT 1;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

and run `CALL updateLastSeenPrice('blablanfff@gmail.com','254857265', 1.11)`

Only the first row (ID 1) gets updated with the price, when I was expecting row ID 10 to update.

This makes no sense to me, the WHERE clause should prevent this from happening, and it's the same query! I've even added a SELECT at the end of the stored procedure to test it's receiving the IN parameters correctly and it is...

Any ideas as to why the first row gets updated? Why is it matching on that when the WHERE clause should prevent it from doing so?

Comment: Don't give parameters the same name as column names. Escaping the column names does not make a difference.

Comment: "MySQL stored procedure UPDATE changing first row only" "Any ideas as to why only the first row gets updated? " Yea remove the LIMIT 1 from the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WHERE clause doesn't see the difference between the column name and parameter name. Therefore, any record will do and it will update the first one.

Change it into:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `updateLastSeenPrice`(
    p_email VARCHAR(100),
    p_productId INT(11),
    p_price FLOAT
)
    DETERMINISTIC
    COMMENT 'Updates watcher last seen price'
BEGIN
    UPDATE 
        `watching`
    SET 
        `lastPriceSeen` = p_price 
    WHERE 
        `email` = p_email AND 
        `productId` = p_productId 
    LIMIT 1;
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```